# Chrome browser not initializing Backbone/Require app in new tab

Tags: google-chrome, backbone.js, requirejs, rendering

This seemed to start happening with a recent Chrome release. I have a pretty standard Backbone application with a router that fires functions on a global view controller. Recently, if you open application links in a new tab, there's a good chance the application never renders until you refresh. I'm assuming Chrome added additional resource reductions to inactive tabs that's causing this but I'm not sure. I'm also not sure how I would get around this. It's a large application but it's packaged up with Require and caches properly so it doesn't reload until I push a new release. It usually loads and renders in less than a second if you've already downloaded the most recent build.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here?

After doing some debugging, it seems that the Require app never initializes because window.onload never fires in the parent Require application script:

```
window.onload = function(){
  require([
    'backbone',
    'builds/app',
    'builds/company/company.router',
    'builds/company/company.hash.redirect',
  ], function( Backbone, App, Router, HashRedirect ){
    App.initializeApp( Router, HashRedirect );
  });
};
```

Here's my page body that loads the require app. I'm using some server configs to load either the built app or the development app, but the problem was on both

```
<body>
  <div id="app" class="app"></div>

  <!-- Load App -->
  <script>
    window.require = {
      waitSeconds: 0
    };
  </script>
  <?php if (App::environment() === 'production' || Config::get('app.production_builds') === TRUE) { ?>
    <script data-main="/apps/company.production.js?bust=<?= Config::get('app.version') ?>" src="/js/libraries/require/require.min.js"></script>
  <?php } else { ?>
    <script data-main="/apps/builds/company/company.develop.js?bust=<?= \Config::get('app.version') ?>" src="/js/libraries/require/require.dev.js"></script>
  <?php } ?>
</body>
```

Removing the window.onload function wrapper from the above initial require closure fixed the problem

```
require([
  'backbone',
  'builds/app',
  'builds/company/company.router',
  'builds/company/company.hash.redirect',
], function( Backbone, App, Router, HashRedirect ){
  App.initialize();
  App.initializeApp( Router, HashRedirect );
});
```

Comment: If `onload` isn't called, it's not related to Backbone nor RequireJS. If you think it's related to Chrome, provide the version number and the behavior in the other browsers you have tested. In this state, the question can't be answered other than by guessing.

Comment: I personally tried opening a new tab and `onload` is called on both pages, so it doesn't seem to be Chrome, but maybe something else in your page that you have not provided.

Comment: Hey haven't put any more thought into this since removing the window.onload wrapper from around the initial require located at the bottom of my require app build script. Other than some bootloaded template and lang info, there is nothing else located within the body tags other than the require script tags. I update my question to demonstrate.